# error with installing odeint <boost/config.hpp>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, installation, odeint

I'm trying to install `odeint` but every time I compile the code, I get this error.

```
c:...odeint\headmyshoulder-odeint-v2-f496df3\include\boost\numeric\odeint\config.hpp(44): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I've included the include path. I checked this file `boost/config.hpp`, this is not a complete path to `<config.hpp>`, so I've changed it to `<boost/numeric/odeint/config.hpp>`. Now I'm getting an error with other files with the same scenario. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you dont have the boost libraries on your system.
odeint requires boost to be available. The easiest way to get both is by just downloading the latest version of boost, which already contains odeint: http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_56_0.html